# inverse of a function and its differentiable

Tags: inverse

I want to prove that this function $f(x)=\frac{x}{\cos x}$ from $(-1,1)$ to $\mathbb R$ is bijective? whether or not has an inverse differentiable?
I know that this function is injective and surjective so is bijective, but I am not able to find its inverse.
thanks.

Comment: Do you mean from $\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: yes, I want to find its inverse function.

Comment: I don't think there is a special function for the inverse, even the cardinal sinus which is more popular doesn't have one.

Comment: what about its inverse differentiable?